# Getting "No Match Found For The Parameter xxxx" error in LoadRunner Controller but the script is working perfectly in VuGen

Tags: controller, loadrunner

Getting "No Match Found For The Parameter xxxx" and "Internal Server Error Status 500"  error in LoadRunner Controller but the script is working perfectly in LoadRunner VuGen without any errors. Vugen and Controller are on same machine. Runtime settings in controller were modified. Random percentage think time 50%-150% was selected. Number of iterations increased.

Error -26377. No match found for the requested parameter 'xxxx'. Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 256 bytes, use web_set_max_htlm_len to increase the parameter size

Error -26612 HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for 'http://local host:8080/xxxxxxxx'

Comment: This question needs some more info. Is VuGen and the Controller in question located on the same machine? Are you using the exact same runtime settings for both VuGen and the Controller (Controller might have different runtime settings that override the ones you have in VuGen)

Comment: Does it fail on the very first iteration when you run it on the Controller? Or does it fail for any subsequent iteration?

Comment: Only one transaction APP_Login (name of transaction) was failing. Rest working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause based upon this error is one rooted in both process and implementation.  You are likely not checking for positive expected results on each step (actual content, not just HTTP 200) and then not branching your code when your positive expected result does not appear.  Your script then continues and your next (or possibly second request) is out of context with the state of the business process, which then results in an HTTP 500.

The process item here is the not checking for expected results as you would with any other type of test, using an assumption that HTTP 200 is just fine.  The implementation item is the code needed to check for the results and then to branch execution when the results do not appear.

The -26377 is simply an artifact of the page you expect to appear not appearing - in this case the HTTP 500 instead of your expected content.

This process and implementation fault is the most common root cause for HTTP 500 appearing in your test results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution :
1. Delete JPetStore, Install it once again
2. Delete temp files, run temp, %temp%
3. Restart system
4. In VuGen, click regenerate script
5. Manually correlate with unique names